# Learning from Unix Programming Environment

Tags: man, documentation

I've got the *Unix Programming Environment* book by Kernighan & Pike, copyright 1984. 
The book says that you need the Unix programmer's manual while reading the book. The preface of the Unix Programming Environment book 
referenced a quote from the Unix programmer's manual 2nd edition June, 1972. Does anyone know if that means that 
that is the edition of the Unix programmer's manual, I should use and/or whether I can use that edition of the manual?
If not so, which edition of Unix programmer's manual should I use, for that edition of the Unix programming Environment book?
I think that maybe someone that read the book, might be more helpful, telling me the manual edition they used.

Finally I've a Windows machine, does anyone know the best option for me to be able to use a Unix terminal, while reading this book

Comment: One difference between 1984 and today is that putting argument types in function declarations was nonexistent back then but is required now.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Cheers mate

Answer (score 4):

The *Unix programmer's manual* is what is better known as the collection of [man pages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_page).

If you're reading *Unix Programming Environment* then it might be helpful to consult the 2nd edition that is cited by that book. You can find copies online, e.g. [from Bell Labs](http://cm.bell-labs.com/7thEdMan/v7vol2a.ps.gz). However it will also be useful to see the manual on your system. You can see individual entries of the manual with the `man` command (that's why they're called “man pages”).

Do note that this is a very old book and 2nd edition is even older. Unix has changed considerably in 35–45 years. To learn Unix, it would be a lot more useful and a lot easier to learn a system that you can run, such as an up-to-date Linux release. Learn this first, and read historical books once you're familiar with the basics.

The best way to learn Linux is to install it on your machine. Start by installing it in a virtual machine. VirtualBox is very easy to use for this. Pick a distribution for novice users, such as Ubuntu, Linux Mint or elementary OS. You can run all the same programs on any distribution, but some distributions are harder to set up than others if you've never done it before.

Comment: Maybe also point to repositories like http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/index.html for contemporary man pages for Linux.  FreeBSD also has its manual on-line at https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi

Comment: Oh, and since the OP asks about Unix rather than Linux, maybe point to FreeBSD as an alternative to Linux, which is less popular, but "more Unix" in some sense. I would not call it suitable for novices, though.

Comment: @tripleee Cheers mate

Comment: @Gilles Cheers mate

Answer (score 2):

1. In 1984 there wasn't really any mass-access Internet, so the only resource for a reference source would have been a book. I suspect these days you'll do just fine with an online connection.
2. Cygwin, Bash on Windows, a Linux/FreeBSD virtual machine, a cheap VPS. There are many options. It's not possible to give a definitive answer because you haven't provided any criteria for *the "best" option*.

Comment: Cheers Roaima. My criteria would be a free one

Comment: @user3856947 VirtualBox works well on Windows, and then just install any popular free Unix, like Ubuntu, or OpenBSD (which is what I'm running on a Windows setup with VirtualBox).

Comment: @Kusalananda  Cheers mate